# Android java video playback background pause doesn't work Please tell me how to solve it

Tags: java, android, kotlin

MainActivity.java

```
@SuppressLint("WrongViewCast")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        IntentFilter powerButtonOff = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        IntentFilter powerButtonOn = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);

        registerReceiver(powerButtonOnOff, powerButtonOff);
        registerReceiver(powerButtonOnOff, powerButtonOn);
```

MainActivity.java

```
private void unregisterBroadcast(){
        unregisterReceiver(powerButtonOnOff);
    }


    BroadcastReceiver powerButtonOnOff = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if(mediaPlayer == null){
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context,R.id.videoView);
            }
            if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
                try {
                    if (mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        mediaPlayer.stop();
                        mediaPlayer.release();
                        mediaPlayer = null;


                    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

MainActivity.java

```
 @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
      unregisterBroadcast();
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DEVICE_POWER"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

hello. The code above should pause playback when the phone is turned off while the video is playing in the app, but it doesn't stop. So I tried the onReceive method by applying the code, but it didn't work, so I don't know the cause.

In Android Java MainActivity.java, if you turn OFF through the onReceive method power key event, the app process screen bounces. I used WAKE_LOCK in AndroidManifest.xml to avoid bouncing, but it doesn't work out well. help.

Comment: Can you let me know why you dont use `onResume` / `onPause` to Play/Pause your playback but On/Off screen event?

Comment: If you turn off the power button while playing a video on your Android phone, it won't play for a long time. After all, even if you turn off the power, the app processor will continue to shut down when you turn on the power that runs in the background.

Comment: I mean you can `onResume` / `onPause` to Play/Pause your playback instead of the above solution

Comment: Is it correct to use the onResum() method in mediaPlayer?

Comment: on `onResume` of activity or fragment, make a call to your mediaplayer to play your playback. And on `onPause` to pause the playback

Comment: Calling the onResume() function will cause the app to bounce in the foreground when launched. Any other workaround?

Answer (score 0):

```
IntentFilter powerButtonOffFilter = new IntentFilter();
powerButtonOffFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
powerButtonOffFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
registerReceiver(powerButtonOnOffReciever, powerButtonOffFilter);
```

In your code you have used same intent filter which only listens for for action screen on as it replaces the screen off due to your code logic.
When you want to listen to multiple broadcast using single intent filter you have to group them and then listen.